# Manual Ajax in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to send ajax request manually in JSF ? If Possible Please Guide me .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Primefaces there is JavaScript API for this. You can use `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest` to do this. See Primefaces Users Guide for this but simple example would be:

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest({
    formId: 'userForm',
    source: 'userForm',
    process: 'userForm'
});
```

This is example from users Guide.

Additionally there is `p:remoteCommand` component with which you can create JavaScript function to call some method from backing bean if this is closer to your use case.

Comment: But i have one more doubt.How to handle it in Managedbean while using Primefaces.ajax.AjaxRequest

Comment: With this you will send inputs, update components. I don't know is there a way to call some `actionListener` with this. But as official user manual said I suggest you to use `p:remoteCommand`, and not to rely on this low level method.

Comment: i'm not able use <p:remoteCommand> Button.I need to use Primefaces.ajax.AjaxRequest and AjaxResponse.

Comment: `p:remoteCommand` is not button. Read documentation and see how it is used. It is completely analogue to manually creating AJAX request with JavaScript but much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [OmniFaces `<o:commandScript>` tag](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript), seems nifty. Also contains lots of other interesting utility for JSF projects.